# How Can I Fix This Runtime Error Being Displayed On My Phone each Time I Try To Run This Application?

Tags: android, mobile, runtime-error

the App is called **"3 Minute Retreat"** by `LoyolaPress` and each time i run it, i get that response; i have tried all the available fixes online and nothing seems to work, from uninstalling to reinstalling, to clearing App and Cache Data, to Soft Rebooting, to moving Storage Location, to downgrading and updating Play Services ETC but nothing seems to work

here is what is being displayed before the "3 Minute Retreat has stopped working" notification comes up:

> "Runtime Error
>   /Users/Jenkins/slaveroot/workspace/Templates/label/Android/subrepos/composer/composer.lua:1451:
>   ?:0 attempt to index a nil value"

NB:
im not a Programmer, so i will really appreciate the easiest form of explanation/instructions that i at least may be able to follow/understand 
and phone is Samsung J1 Ace (4.4.4)

Comment: Point of information - The message "3 Minute Retreat has stopped working" means that the app has crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the code around line 1451 in composer.lua file.

From the error it looks like you're trying to index a null object.

Try to debug the actual value of the variables being accessed during runtime, and try to figure out why the variable is null.